# Edit data from table with javascript and php from ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am a beginner in PHP and Javascript I used a live editable table and I am trying to edit them and then save them to mysql in another page I did like this, but I didn't know how to retrieve where to edit in mysql with the `id` could some one help please! Am i wrong in the request? it doesn't change in the database like it does in the table in the page. I sent the data like this:

```
function postedit()
    {
        var _type = $('#typeid').val();
        var _pression = $('#pressionid').val();   
        var _code = $('input[name="code"]').val();
        var _designiation = $('input[name="designiation"]').val();
        var _diametre = $('input[name="diametre"]').val();
        var _epaisseur = $('input[name="epaisseur"]').val();
        var _prix = $('input[name="prix"]').val();
        var _etat = $('input[name="etat"]').val();

        $.post('update.php', {
            posttype: _type,
            postpression: _pression,
            postcode: _code,
            postdesigniation: _designiation,
            postdiametre: _diametre,
            postepaisseur: _epaisseur,
            postprix:_prix,
            postetat:_etat
        },
        function(data){
            $('tbody').append(data);
        });
    }

var _trEdit = null;

$(document).on('click', '.btn-edit',function(){
    _trEdit = $(this).closest('tr');
    var _code = $(_trEdit).find('td:eq(0)').text();
    var _designiation = $(_trEdit).find('td:eq(1)').text();
    var _diametre = $(_trEdit).find('td:eq(2)').text();
    var _epaisseur = $(_trEdit).find('td:eq(3)').text();
    var _prix = $(_trEdit).find('td:eq(4)').text();
    var _etat = $(_trEdit).find('td:eq(5)').text();

    $('input[name="code"]').val(_code);
    $('input[name="designiation"]').val(_designiation);
    $('input[name="diametre"]').val(_diametre);
    $('input[name="epaisseur"]').val(_epaisseur);
    $('input[name="prix"]').val(_prix);
    $('input[name="etat"]').val(_etat);
});

$('#btn-update').click(function(){
    if(_trEdit){
        var _code = $('input[name="code"]').val();
        var _designiation = $('input[name="designiation"]').val();
        var _diametre = $('input[name="diametre"]').val();
        var _epaisseur = $('input[name="epaisseur"]').val();
        var _prix = $('input[name="prix"]').val();
        var _etat = $('input[name="etat"]').val();

        $(_trEdit).find('td:eq(0)').text(_code);
        $(_trEdit).find('td:eq(1)').text(_designiation);
        $(_trEdit).find('td:eq(2)').text(_diametre);
        $(_trEdit).find('td:eq(3)').text(_epaisseur);
        $(_trEdit).find('td:eq(4)').text(_prix);
        $(_trEdit).find('td:eq(5)').text(_etat);

        alert("Ligne Modifier avec succée !");
        _trEdit = null;
    }
});
```

My sql request in a file `update.php` like this I thought that if I get the `id` from the database and search from it, it seems stupid but I am desperate:

```
$type_utilisation = $_POST['posttype'];
$pression_tube = $_POST['postpression'];
$code_tube = $_POST['postcode'];
$designiation_tube = $_POST['postdesigniation'];
$diametre_tube = $_POST['postdiametre'];
$epaisseur_tube = $_POST['postepaisseur'];                       
$prix_tube = $_POST['postprix'];
$etat_tube = $_POST['postetat'];
$id_req = ("select id from $pression_tube where      typepehd='".$type_utilisation."' && code='".$code_tube."'");
$id_tube=$id_req;
echo"$id_tube";

if(isset($pression_tube)){
    if($pression_tube=="pn4"){
        if($type_utilisation=="pehdtelecom" && $pression_tube=="pn4" ){
            echo "verifier le type du Tube S.v.p";
        } else {
            $sql="UPDATE  pn4 SET    typepehd='".$type_utilisation."',code='".$code_tube."',designiation='".$designiation_tube."',diametre='".$diametre_tube."',epaisseur='".$epaisseur_tube."',prix='".$prix_tube."',etat='".$etat_tube."' where id='".$id_tube."'";      

            $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

            if($result){
            } else {
                echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: First of all, in your `JavaScript` where are you calling `postedit()`? And then you have a lot of issues in your `php` code. You are assigning a string(query) to `$id_req` but never running the `query`. That's why you are ending having `string` in `$id_tube`(the select query) instead of actual `id` field. Why are you using `$pression_tube` as table name? why don't you simply use the table name(pn4 I assume!) instead in your `select` query? And last your code is open to `sql injection`. Please use `prepared statement` to fix it.

Comment: thank you, but i am trying to find a solution how to retreave the id of the row to put the id in the where close to update the row, is there a solution other than select it from the databse ?

Comment: You are selecting on the same table which you are updating. So there is no need for two queries. you can just update the table with the conditions of the select query! something like this: `"update pn4 set (Your fields and their values...) where typepehd='".$type_utilisation."' and code='".$code_tube."'"`

Comment: its sending edited data to the php file so The retrieved values are the newest values entered so it will not find them in where clause. this is why i tried to find the id. have any other solution to do so ? please

Comment: thank you, i did solve it by using the id because its unique $id_tube = $_POST['postid']; by  adding an input to it in type hidden <input type="hidden" id="idrow" placeholder="Id" class="form-control"> and make the column invisible by style="display;none";

Answer (score 0):

thank you, i did solve it by using the id because its unique

```
 $id_tube = $_POST['postid'];
```

by adding an input to it in type hidden 
     
 and make the column invisible by

```
 style="display;none";
```